# auth protected pages in rails 4 application how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a redirect loop. I have a clear idea why, user is logged out, redirected to login page (welcome#index) and user is still logged out and we have an endless loop.

How do I get out of loop?

I read about several options.

1. before_action `:require_login placing` it inside controllers where login is required. EASY, but a lot of copy paste, we love dry don't' we?
2. except, before_action `:require_login, :except => root`? I couldn't find details about except. I'm getting a lot of hits on `before_filter` which seems to be deprecated.
3. `skip_before_action` same here, I can only find bits and pieces :(
4. There should be a better way to handle these, is it rails way to do check routes level in config/routes.rb?

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user
  before_action :require_login

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= Dedit::User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  private
  def require_login
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.present?
  end
end
```

login page controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    layout 'basic'

    def index
    if current_user.present? then redirect_to dedit_path end
    end
end
```

Comment: you could also add  `skip_before_action :require_login` to the `WelcomeController` this will not require the user to login to access any pages contained in this controller.

Comment: I actually tried this way, but got no results @engineersmnky but I just realised I had to do skip_before_action :require_login in sessioncontroller too! :) and it works now.

Comment: glad it worked for you you just have to make sure any page that should be accessible without login has the proper `skip_before_action` line and rails will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
before_action :require_login, except: [:index]
```

Comment: When I put index, redirect_to root_path unless current_user.present? doesn't work anymore. no redirect happens.